# Show a dialog asking user to continue or abort

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new in C# and I'm sorry for asking for a very simple question.

I have 2 classes, `Form1.cs` and `Testing.cs`

1. I write a function in Testing.cs and it has many processing steps. I want at every step, user must confirm that they want to continue processing the next step. If they don't want to do that, they click on Abort to stop processing. How can I do this because I can't call `DialogResult` in class `Testing` to display a dialog.
2. In class Testing, after every processed step I have a sting update its status. I don't know how to send this string instantly to the form to show the status on a textbox.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: For the first point, what is the problem with calling MessageBox.Show?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of many questions asking how to pass a value to a form. There are very many possible solutions, many that are easier than using a delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first point could be solved easily by MessageBox.Show that contains all the necessary functionality to show a Yes/No option

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to continue?", 
                                   "Your App Title",
                                   MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                                   MessageBoxIcon.Question,
                                   MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

if(dr == DialogResult.No)
    return;
```

The second problem is a bit more complex but it could be resolved using delegates

Suppose that your Form1 class calls the testing class passing a delegate that should be called by the testing class everytime it needs to inform the Form1 class of something.

In Form1 class you write

```
  Testing t = new Testing();
  t.MultipleStepsOperation((string status) => 
           { 
               MessageBox.Show("Testing class calls Form class with status=" + status);
           });
```

in testing class you receive the delegate passed by the Form class

```
  public void MultipleStepsOperation(Action<string> formNotifier)
  {
      string status = "Initialize ops";
      if(formNotifier != null)
         // Invoke is not required, just for clarity
         // formNotifier(status); // the same as below...
         formNotifier.Invoke(status);
      ....

      status = "Executing step 1";
      if(formNotifier != null)
         formNotifier.Invoke(status);

      status = "Executing step 2";      
      if(formNotifier != null)
         formNotifier.Invoke(status);
      ....

  }
```